Como saber que ventana está activa en SAP? (scripting)
Hola y muchas gracias por leer mi mensaje.
Tengo un código que ejecuta una transacción de SAP en la ventana 0 (wnd[0]) y en general funciona bien, pero hay veces que no tengo datos y esto abre una nueva ventana en sap (wnd[1]). Quisiera saber como puedo detectar si sigo en la wnd[0] o si hubo un error y se activó la wnd[1] sin que me dé un error en tiempo de ejecución. En principio estoy usando Python, pero si con vbscript es más sencillo podría cambiarme.
Desde ya muchas gracias por el aporte que puedan darme.

Ni idea de qué es wnd o como te comunicas al SAP, pero si hablamos de Windows y si el objeto wnd te puede entregar el handle nativo de la ventana (HWND), podrías interrogar al sistema operativo y, comparando el resultado, saber si tiene el foco.

Gracias jachguate. El wnd es el la forma en que el lenguaje de SAPScript se refiere a las ventanas. La 0 es la principal y, en general, cuando surge algún mensaje o se interroga al usuario (por ejemplo donde va a grabar la información) se despliega una nueva ventana que suele ser la wnd[1].
Igualmente esto que comentas me ha dado una nueva pista por donde investigar. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
